# Java Object is root of all classes not all other objects

Tags: java

I know that `java.lang.Object` class is superclass of all classes. It is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has `Object` as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

But I read that `Object` is root of all classes not all other objects and I didn't understand it.

Comment: can you give a citation of where you read this?

Comment: Objects are things that exist only while your program is running.  Classes are things that also exist before your program starts and after your program ends.  Does that help?

Comment: @TallChuck I found it in this QCM https://www.briefmenow.org/oracle/which-three-statements-describe-the-object-oriented-fea/

Comment: I have no idea what I just read

Comment: Your site says "`Object` is the root class of all other objects." which is a little inaccurate. Better would be sth like "`Object` is the root class of all other objects' classes". Because a class is the blueprint of an object or object is an instance of a class. `Object` is a class, "objects" are instances of a class that inherits from `Object`

Comment: Plus one - yes Java is a mess when it comes to this. Facetiously everything is derived from java.lang.Object except those things that are not.

Comment: @zapl Thanks this answers my question

Answer (score 5):

All classes inherit from the `Object` class. That means all objects (`String`, `LinkedList`, any objects you create, etc) get all the methods `Object` contains. However, not all variables are objects, in Java parlance. There are also [primitive data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), like `int`, `char`, etc. From the Java documentation:

> Primitive types are special data types built into the language; they are not objects created from a class.

Comment: That means that all "classes" (String , LinkedList  any "class you instanciate", etc

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Object

public class Object

Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. 
Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html